# How to filter serviceNow incident records based on sys_updated_on

Tags: java, xml, web-services, servicenow

I'm using xml web service for service-now to query on the incident records. I'm using java and apache Httpscomponents to make calls. Since I am having a large number of records, In want to filter those records based on the sys_updated_on. What I tried is passing below uri to the HTTPGet

```
https://<instance>-now.com/incident.do?CSV&sys_param_query=active=true^sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate(2016-12-01,03:50:00)@javascript:gs.dateGenerate(2016-12-01,03:55:00)
```

But this doesn't worked for me as it is returning all records, not the filtered ones.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here and the correction too.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution from servenow.com only.

```
https://<instance>-now.com/incident_list.do?sysparm_query=sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.dateGenerate('2016-12-01'%2C'00%3A00%3A00')%40javascript%3Ags.dateGenerate('2016-11-20'%2C'23%3A59%3A59')
```

or

```
https://<instance>-now.com/incident_list.do?sysparm_query=sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.dateGenerate('2016-12-01','00:00:00')%40javascript%3Ags.dateGenerate('2016-11-20','23:59:59')
```

how did I found this? On your_instance.servicenow.com, when we press on the filter button, a filter line is shown in its right, right click on that and select copy url. Attached is the image for same.
[image: query]
[image: query]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure date and time strings are in quotes.

```
https://<instance>-now.com/incident.do?CSV&sys_param_query=active=true^sys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript:gs.dateGenerate('2016-12-01','03:50:00')@javascript:gs.dateGenerate('2016-12-01','03:55:00')
```

Comment: Didn't helped. Still returning all the records

Comment: yes, I am encoding url.  Earlier I encoded the full url, but that gave me some exceptions. Then after trying some more solutions, I found that I need to encode just the ^ character which %5E .

Comment: Also, the issue is with the url . Because when I paste this query in web browser, a csv is downloaded, again all the records (not the filtered ones). I want to know what is the query to get the filtered record.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me from the browser at least, one difference I see is in the way the date's are formatted in your snippet:

```
https://<instance_url>/incident_list.do?CSV&amp;sysparm_query=active%3Dtrue%5Estate!%3D6%5Esys_updated_onBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.dateGenerate('2016-11-01'%2C'00%3A00%3A00')%40javascript%3Ags.dateGenerate('2016-12-07'%2C'23%3A59%3A59')
```

Comment: Not working for me. Even  if I provide a date of 2018, same records are downloading even though I don't have any record for 2018 date.